# How to make bank account review and transactions in R

Tags: r, transactions, account, bank

I would like to enter into my bank account, read my savings and credit account balances and make some operations if possible with an R program. Is this ever possible ?

I read:

http://www.learnbymarketing.com/1043/working-with-arules-transactions-and-read-transactions/

but this did not help much as it should be about a certain transaction format. I need piece of code for logging in to my account in

https://www.yapikredi.com.tr/

with my password and passcode. Pressing red button "Internet Subesi" and "Bireysel Bankacılık" opens login window with html address:

https://internetsube.yapikredi.com.tr/ngi/7b1a47853117a11ac0dc80ceb4d71a5b.do?lang=tr

and I should be reading the some useful info from the coming html page(s).

Would this ever be possible in R ? I would be the most happiest if this is possible. Thank you.

Comment: How are you downloading your bank account transactions? Are they csv's?

Comment: excel and pdf options are possible, buttons of which resides inside my accounts page.

Comment: You could look into using `RSelenium` for browser automation

Comment: I'll be wary of any non-encrypted connection to my bank, though...

Comment: R has lots of ways to read excel files, that's probably the simplest.

Comment: I have no problem with reading excel files in R, thanks, first things first, may be I should start with asking about how to remotely enter username/password into a web site in R..